# How to include penalisation in Hat matrix?

Tags: r, smoothing, non-linear-regression, loess, regularized

I am trying to optimize the span value of a LOESS fit based on GCV. Below is the code I am using.

```html
gcv.calc <- function(span){
  for (sp in span)
  {
    fit <- loess(y ~ x, data = df, span = sp)
    res <- residuals(fit)
    sse <- sum(res ^ 2)
    
    ## Calculate trace of Hat Matrix
    H <- X %*% (solve(t(X) %*% X)%*% t(X))  ### solve() calculates the inverse of a matrix
    traceMat <- sum(diag(H))
  
    GCV <- (n * sse) / (n - traceMat) ^ 2
    cal[[length(cal)+1]] = GCV
  }
  return(cal)

}

span <- seq(from = 0. 1, to = 0.5, by = 0.01)
output <- gcv.calc(span)
```

I want to incorporate LOESS smoothing so that the degrees of freedom gets adjusted as span changes and to minimise the degrees of freedom to get GCVS as low as possible.

How to incorporate the regularization parameter and smoothing constraint to the hat matrix?